# For Loop with Different Velocities in R

Tags: r

I am trying to build a loop that creates urls with 70 years and 50 pages per year.  Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

```
    yrs <- 1919
    pgs <- 0
urltest <- as.character()
yrsrepeat <- 0

for(i in 1:70){
    yrs[i] <- yrs + i
    pgs[i] <- pgs + i
    yrsrepeat[i] <- rep.int(yrs[i], length(pgs))
    urltest[i] <- paste0(url1, yrs[i], url2, url3, pgs[i], url4)
  }



url1 <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=0&season=2017&month=0&season1=1920&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0&page=1_30"
url2 <- "_30"
pages <- 1:5


url1 <- "https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=y&type=8&season="
url2 <- "&month=0&season1="
url3 <- "&ind=0&team=&rost=&age=&filter=&players=&page="
url4 <- "_30"
year <- 1920:1924
pages <- 1:5

urls <- paste0(url1, year, url2, year, url3, pages, url4)
```

Comment: `paste` and `rep` are vectorized.  You don't need a loop.   Please include a complete reproducible example with expected output.  The 'url's are not defined.  Something like `paste0(url1, (yrs:(yrs + 0:69), url2, url3, (pgs:(pgs + 0:69)), url4)`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then,  I would do something similar to this:

```
urls = list() # to store each year's urls

for(i in 1930:1999){

    current_year_urls = paste("url",i ,"pg", 1:50,sep = "") 

    # check if first year
    if (length(urls) == 0){
        urls = current_year_urls

    }else{
       # if not first year, append it to the list
       urls = rbind(urls,current_year_urls)
    }
```

Comment: But I also need the 50 pages...  Ex. url1930pg1, url1930pg2, etc